# Userscript won't close window if it isn't active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm brand new to StackOverflow and userscripts, and I'm trying to get a fresh start!

Worthless information aside, I'm having a bit of trouble with a tiny script I recently whipped up.

```
(function () {

  $("#enbut").click();

  setTimeout(function () {
    open(location, '_self');
    window.close();
  }, 100);

})();
```

What it does is clicks a button, waits a second for the website to register that I've clicked it, and then it closes the webpage.

The only issue that I am having is that it does not seem to want to close the webpage when the tab isn't the one I currently have active (Opened up so I can see it).

The script works fine if I open the webpage directly, but if I right click and open in a new tab, it's able to click the button, but the page doesn't close until I open up the tab.

Is there any reason this would be happening, or any way to fix it?

I'm using Chrome, so maybe it's just a browser security feature like what they have done with closing windows?

Comment: I think that is a security thing, I played around with your script and got this message in my console: `Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.` (and if you right click that's probably not the case). If you explain what is behind your script we might be able to suggest another way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and yes, it appears that it is due to a security issue with Chrome. I was able to resolve this by setting it up as a Chrome extension, which gives it higher privileges and the ability to close windows as it pleases. Thanks for the idea, that helped!

Comment: Would you mind telling us in an answer what the solution is?

Comment: @Huntereb Post the answer so it might help someone..

Comment: You might as well accept the answer as well so that it is officially "solved".

Answer (score 1):

`window.close();` throws a security issue when used as a general userscript in today's browsers. Even when using the work around ( `open(location, '_self');` ), it does not seem to allow it in tabs that are not the active window.

In order to resolve this, I had to convert the userscript to a Chrome Extension, which gives the script full control over Chrome's security measures. I don't think there would be any other way to get this working as a plain userscript without messing with Chrome's internals, which would be a stupid thing to do for a simple script.

Thanks for the help, guys!

Comment: After a while, the system will let you accept your own answer. That is the best way to make something as 'Solved' here at Stack Overflow.